# Site works but Facebook debugger Curl error: 28 (OPERATION_TIMEOUTED)

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, connection-timeout, facebook-debugger

I have website developed using nodejs and react server side rendering.
When i am trying to scrape my website with facebook debugger, facebook takes more than 10 sec and times out. However I noticed that my web server responds to facebook scraper request within few milliseconds.

Also, Page performance is fine and it serves in less than 2 secs at max.
Note: FB debugger can scrape my website homepage (which is static file) without any issues. Not sure what is causing facebook debugger to timeout.

Any ideas?
[image: screenshot of facebook debugger]

Comment: make sure you don't have any loops that may keep your node endpoint to load infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I had path which was blocking the request, fixing that but fixed the issue.
@souhailhimself thank you for pointing in the right direction.